# Restrict the scope of a command to the execution of another command

Tags: macros, footnotes, scoping

In one section of a document I used

```
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{}
```

to have a footnote without number.

The problem is that it propagates through the whole document then and all footnotes appear to have no index.

How can I restrict the influence of this command to one particular footnote?

Update:
I use unnumbered footnotes at the beginning of the chapter to specify, for instance, the version of software used throughout the chapter. It is common to do it like that in the community I am working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Redefine the command in a group; using `\footnotetext` instead of `\footnote` will not increment the footnote counter as the following example shows

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\nofootnote}[1]{%
  \begingroup\def\thefootnote{}\footnotetext{#1}\endgroup}

\setlength{\textheight}{10cm} % just for showing the result

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}
\nofootnote{This chapter describes version 1 of the software}

Here's the text with a numbered footnote\footnote{Here it is}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The name `\nofootnote` for the user macro may come across as a bit self-conflicted. Might `\footnotewithoutnum` avoid this issue?

Comment: Very simple an very nice solution. Cogratulation.